# Deploy Docker Image into AKS cluster using Azure Release Pipelines with the parameters like clustername, acr, resourcegroup

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-aks, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I started learning azure devops pipeline trying to Deploy Docker Image into AKS cluster using Azure Release Pipelines ex: simple python app,create docker image and deploy docker image into AKS cluster with dynamic user input parameters **but image parameter value from yml script in the pipeline the value is not getting picked**. Assist the with any doc's or syntax if i missed here Thanks in advance!

```
parameters:
- name: 'containerRegistry'
  displayName: 'Azure Container Registry'
  type: object
 
- name: 'ResourceGroup'
  displayName: 'Azure ResourceGroup'
  type: object

- name: 'Cluster'
  displayName: 'Azure Cluster'
  type: object

pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build image
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - task: Docker@0
      displayName: 'Build an image'
      inputs:
        #command: build
        azureSubscription: 'TEST'
        azureContainerRegistry: ${{ parameters.containerRegistry }}.azurecr.io
        action: 'Build an image'
        dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
        includeLatestTag: true

    - task: Docker@0
      displayName: 'Push an image'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'TEST'
        azureContainerRegistry: ${{ parameters.containerRegistry }}.azurecr.io
        action: 'Push an image'
        includeLatestTag: true

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
      inputs:
        Contents: 'azure-aks.yaml'
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'

- stage: DeployToKubernetes
  displayName: 'Deploy to Kubernetes'
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: 'Release pipeline'
    environment: 'dev'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - download: current
            artifact: 'drop'
            displayName: 'Download Artifact'

          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                $aksYamlPath = "/home/vsts/work/1/drop/azure-aks.yaml"
                $containerRegistry = "${{ parameters.containerRegistry }}.azurecr.io"
                $content = Get-Content -Path $aksYamlPath -Raw
                $content = $content -replace '\${{ parameters.containerRegistry }}', $containerRegistry
                Set-Content -Path $aksYamlPath -Value $content
            displayName: 'Replace Container Registry in YAML


          - task: Kubernetes@1
            displayName: 'Create Deployments & Services in AKS'
            inputs:
              connectionType: 'Azure Resource Manager'
              azureSubscriptionEndpoint: 'TEST'
              azureResourceGroup: ${{ parameters.ResourceGroup }}
              kubernetesCluster: ${{ parameters.Cluster }}
              useClusterAdmin: true
              namespace: default
              command: apply
              useConfigurationFile: true
              configuration:  '/home/vsts/work/1/drop/azure-aks.yaml' 
              azureContainerRegistry: ${{ parameters.containerRegistry }}
              checkLatest: true 
                
azure-aks.yaml
--------------
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-python-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-python-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-python-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: dockerfile
        image: ${{ parameters.containerRegistry }}.azurecr.io/dockerfile:latest  ## value for image is not getting populated from pipeline
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000       
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-python-app-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-python-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: Please refer to https://thomasthornton.cloud/2021/12/16/build-and-push-docker-images-to-azure-container-registry-using-azure-devops-pipelines/ -   [Build and deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service with Azure Pipelines (pipelines-yaml)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/devops-pipeline?pivots=pipelines-yaml#build-and-deploy-to-azure-kubernetes-service-with-azure-pipelines)
-   [Create a pipeline with YAML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline-cli?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Cyaml%2Cbrowser)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by that the `'\${{ parameters.containerRegistry }}'` expression is not correct in your powershell task.

To replace the image string in `azure-aks.yaml` within powershell task, i fixed the task with below:

```
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                $aksYamlPath = "/home/vsts/work/1/drop/azure-aks.yaml"
                $containerRegistry = "${{ parameters.containerRegistry }}"           # remove .azurecr.io as it alreadys exsits in your azure-aks.yaml
                $content = Get-Content -Path $aksYamlPath -Raw
                $content = $content -replace '\$\{\{ parameters\.containerRegistry \}\}', $containerRegistry        # fix the expression
                Set-Content -Path $aksYamlPath -Value $content
                cat $aksYamlPath
            displayName: 'Replace Container Registry in YAML'
```

I added `cat $aksYamlPath` at the end to check the yaml content, my pipeline result:

[image]